# Export DataFrame into csv with " "

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, formatting, export

I am trying to export a DataFrame into csv file with Python 3 using the code below:

```
import pandas as pds    
oee_2016 = pds.DataFrame({'"title"':['"OEE"', '"Qual"', '"Perf"', '"Disp"'],
                          '"subtitle"':['"%"', '"%"', '"%"', '"%"'],
                          '"ranges__001"':['"40"', '"75"', '"75"', '"75"'],
                          '"ranges__002"':['"60"', '"85"', '"85"', '"85"'],
                          '"ranges__003"':['"100"', '"100"', '"100"', '"100"'],
                          '"measures__001"':['"12"', '"34"', '"56"', '"78"'],
                          '"measures__002"':['"0"', '"0"', '"0"', '"0"'],
                          '"markers__-"':['"85"', '"95"', '"95"', '"95"']
                         })
oee_2016.to_csv('oee_2016.csv', index=False)
```

and the result is:

*"""title""","""subtitle""","""ranges__001""","""ranges__002""","""ranges__003""","""measures__001""","""measures__002""","""markers__-"""
"""OEE""","""%""","""40""","""60""","""100""","""12""","""0""","""85"""
"""Qual""","""%""","""75""","""85""","""100""","""34""","""0""","""95"""
"""Perf""","""%""","""75""","""85""","""100""","""56""","""0""","""95"""
"""Disp""","""%""","""75""","""85""","""100""","""78""","""0""","""95"""*

but I would like just one " not """, like this: "OEE", not """OEE""".

Anybody knows what happens? How to code corret?

Answer (score 0):

When you then open that result in Excel, it looks like the values you entered originally: each value has quotes around it. Pandas has saved the file in such a way that Excel will reproduce the quotes you put in; it needed triple quotes in the csv file to achieve that effect.

This is probably not what you intended to do. It is better to have no quotes in the DataFrame object, and let the `to_csv` method insert them (just once) in the output file:

```
import pandas as pds    
oee_2016 = pds.DataFrame({'title':['OEE', 'Qual', 'Perf', 'Disp'],
                          'subtitle':['%', '%', '%', '%'],
                          'ranges__001':['40', '75', '75', '75'],
                          'ranges__002':['60', '85', '85', '85'],
                          'ranges__003':['100', '100', '100', '100'],
                          'measures__001':['12', '34', '56', '78'],
                          'measures__002':['0', '0', '0', '0'],
                          'markers__-':['85', '95', '95', '95']
                         })
oee_2016.to_csv('oee_2016.csv', index=False, quoting=1)
```

Note the additional argument `quoting=1` to the `to_csv` method.